# What configuration and bundles are required to run an Eclipse RAP application on GlassFish 3.0?

Tags: glassfish, eclipse-rap

I have an Eclipse plugin which I've written using the RAP 1.4m2 target. It runs fine using the Eclipse launcher and Equinox 3.7 (which is the default in Eclipse 3.6) . I have also configured my GlassFish 3 server to use Equinox 3.7 for OSGI. I haven't been able to get my bundle to start in this environment, however. What other configuration or bundles are needed to run a generic Eclipse plugin under RAP on Equinox 3.7 and GlassFish 3? Is there a simple resource that can help me do this?

Comment: To answer your question, it's important to know whether you use the Eclipse workbench and the extension registry. If you're using Equinox, you should be able to connect to the Equinox console. Please enter the `ss` command for a list of installed bundles and their state.